# Angular6: Pass data from navheader to routed component

Tags: routes, angular6

I'm pretty new to Angular and I came across a problem where my postfilter and post sort order are part of the navheader. They only appear when the current route is the home route. I'm trying to figure out how to pass de postfilter's value (soon to be observable, not yet implemented as observable) and the sort order to my dashboard component, which contains the postcomponent.

**Navheader HTML**

```
  <div *ngIf="this.router.url==='/'">
    <div style="padding-left: 5%">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Sort by...</button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Popularity</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Date</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
      <mat-card>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Filter by title" type="text" #filter />
        </mat-form-field>
        <button (click)="applyFilter(filter.value)" mat-raised-button>
          Filter
        </button>
      </mat-card>
  </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="/">
          <span class="label">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

**Navheader TS**

```
export class NavheaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Where the value from the filter should end up**

```
export class DashboardComponent {
-->>@Input() public filterPostTitle: string; <<--

  constructor(private _postDataService: PostDataService) {}

  get posts(): Post[] {
    return this._postDataService.posts;
  }

  addNewPost(post) {
    this._postDataService.addNewPost(post);
  }
}
```

**Routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutes {}
```

It's important that the filter is an observable, so I think passing it as route value isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you put your filters in the dashboard component? Seems like you are mixing concerns between your navcomponent (which should only handle navigation concerns) and your dashboard component (which should handle visualization, filtering, etc)

Comment: since it looks cleaner when the filter fills the blankspace in my nav and I have no idea if it's possible to put an element in another component with css